# Invalid field name by using GetFieldAsString from ogr.py

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr, python-2.7, osgeo

I use a little algorithm to transform values from an openstreetmap-file into a table (.dbf).

I use the function: GetFieldAsString("string") from ogr.py and everything is fine, but when the "string" contains a char like "_" or ":" the error:

```
ERROR1: Invalid field name: 'string_string'
```

appear.

(The function I use comes from [there](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-new-shapefile-and-add-data))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name is too long. [DBF](http://www.johnbrown.com.au/approach/webfaq04040210.html) is a *really* old format and has a maximum field name length of 10 characters and the only characters allowed are [A-Z][0-9] and underscores "_"

Comment: Okay, that explains a lot...
Is there any way to circumvent these restrictions? For example, with another file format?
And could QGIS handle another format then?

Comment: @freddykrueger https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150519/need-a-vector-format-that-is-editable-in-qgis-and-supports-10-character-column